# Mac OS X error: directory that is not on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pythonpath, pth

I'm getting an error while trying to install FEnicS on Mac OS X 10.11.6. I've read the responses to similar questions on this website, and have tried the suggested solutions, but I must be doing something wrong.

On running the command:

```
curl -s https://fenicsproject.org/fenics-install.sh | bash
```

I get an error while the cython package is being installed:

```
[cython] Building cython/e2t4ieqlgjl3, follow log with:  
[cython]   tail -f /Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/tmp/cython-e2t4ieqlgjl3-1/_hashdist/build.log
[cython|ERROR] Command '[u'/bin/bash', '_hashdist/build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1
[cython|ERROR] command failed (code=1); raising.
```

The message from build.log is:

> Checking .pth file support in
>   /Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/bld/cython/e2t4ieqlgjl3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
>   /Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/bld/python/pf77qttkbtzn/bin/python -E -c pass
>
> TEST FAILED:
>   /Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/bld/cython/e2t4ieqlgjl3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
>   does NOT support .pth files  error: bad install directory or
>   PYTHONPATH
>
> You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not on
>   PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
>   installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
>   the distutils default setting) was:
>
> /Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/bld/cython/e2t4ieqlgjl3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
>
> and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains: 
>   '/Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/bld/cython/e2t4ieqlgjl3/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:'
>
> Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:
>
> - You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files
> - You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run Python
>     and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)
> - You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by  using one of the approaches described here:
>
> https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

I've tried adding this to the bash_profile, but get the same error:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/sophiaw/.hashdist/bld/cython/e2t4ieqlgjl3/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you "source" the `.bash_profile` file (using the dot `.`) command, or logoff/login after the edit?

Comment: @cdarke I did source it, but got the same error

Comment: Just trying to install this myself on OS X......

Comment: @cdarke thank you! I await your response

Comment: Sorry, I have been unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking @cdarke , so were you able to install FEniCS without any problems then? any suggestions for fixing this problem? thanks again for looking into this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was resolved by the fenics support group. to install FEniCS on OS X, Docker is a more convenient option.